# JavaScript with function having inconsistent return points

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

Let's say I have this Class:

```
function Point(x,y){
  var _x=x,_y=y;
  this.x = function(newX){
    if (typeof newX !== 'undefined') {
      //function x() working as a setter
      _x=newX;
    }
    else {
      //function x() working as a getter
      return _x;
    }
  }
}
```

PHPStorm complains about the function (x()) having inconsistent return points. I found that adding `return undefined;` just after `_x=newX;` solves the whine and the code looks like this.

```
function Point(x,y){
  var _x=x,_y=y;
  this.x = function(newX){
    if (typeof newX !== 'undefined') {
      //function x() working as a setter
      _x=newX;
      return undefined;
    }
    else {
      //function x() working as a getter
      return _x;
    }
  }
}
```

The question is: Is there a way to make PHPStorm stop whining about this?

Comment: Oh god yes, this is annoying. Generally, when a JetBrains IDE complains about something, you can turn it off. Click on the warning and you'll see the option. That said, in your case - you can invert the `if` and flow control will remain the same.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I know. The code here is nothing but a quick example (inverting the IF statement gives the same warning), but it's extremely annoying to have the IDE complaining about this, specially for large projects. I don't like the idea of disabling it because sometimes it becomes handy to have the warning about a function not returning proper data, what I end up doing is setting it as an information type of notification, but then I might end up omitting some real issues :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to annotate the methods return type properly, so that PhpStorm knows that the function is expected to return `undefined` in some cases.

```
/**
 * @param {number} [newX]
 * @returns {number|undefined}
 */
this.x = function(newX) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is definitely the right approach.  Unfortunately it doesn't work for PHP code.  It still complains with the annotation "@return array|void".  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can suppress the warning for this function only, like:

```
//noinspection FunctionWithInconsistentReturnsJS
    this.x = function(newX){
...
}
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing for a while, the problem with this solution is that it actually disables the inspection for the function. As @ndm posted, adding the jsDoc {some_type|undefined} (being "undefined" the key part) is the way to go (at least for me).